# How to use shell32.dll from C++ console application

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

What I need to do is to get `ApplicationData` path , I've found in Google that there is function called

```
HRESULT SHGetFolderPath(
  __in   HWND hwndOwner,
  __in   int nFolder,
  __in   HANDLE hToken,
  __in   DWORD dwFlags,
  __out  LPTSTR pszPath
);
```

But it exists in shell32.dll
In C# I'd do something like

```
[DllImport]
static extern HRESULT SHGetFolderPath() and so on.
```

What do I need to do in C++ Console application, to be able to call this API?
Maybe, I can use `LoadLibrary()`? 
But what is the right way to do this?

Can I somehow statically link this dll to be part of my exe?
I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to #include shlobj.h and link to shell32.lib.  Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <assert.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, path);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    // etc..
    return 0;
}
```

The #pragma comment takes care of telling the linker about it.

Comment: Any reason why you used the #pragma instead of just adding it under linker options?

Comment: @Jesse, because it is *so* much easier to explain.  And there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

`#include <Shlobj.h>` and `#pragma comment(lib,"Shell32.lib")` should work.