# Problems formatting arrays and strings in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a simple problem that's been driving me nuts all day. I am trying to open a file on the current user's Desktop without knowing the current user's name.

The idea is that I would use the GetCurrentUser call to the API to get the user name. Then format a string to give the full path directory, and pass that variable into fopen to open the file. Here is the code I'm working on, I get no compiler errors and it compiles fine but nothing writes to the file.

```
int main() {

  char pathName[200]; // declaring arrays

  char userName[100];

  DWORD userNameSize = sizeof(userName); // storage for user name

  if (!GetUserName(userName, &userNameSize)) { cout << "user not found"; }

  else { cout "hello" << userName;} // error checking


  // format for Windows 7 desktop
  sprintf(pathName, "\"C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\text.txt\"", userName); 

  cout << pathName << "\n"; // confirms correct location

  const char* fileLocation = pathName; // pointer to full path to pass into fputs

  const char* test = "test";  // test information to write to file to confirm

  FILE *f = fopen(fileLocation,"a+"); // open file in append mode

  fputs(test, f); // write to file

  fclose(f); // flush and exit

  return 0;
}
```

Maybe I need to use a different call to format the string? Or declare fileLocation as a different variable type?

I'm fairly new to C++ and would appreciate any tips that would help me to be able to open a file on the current user's Desktop. Thanks.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO JERRY'S ADVICE:

This is what my latest comment was referring to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

string location ("C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\log.dat");

char cstr = char* [location.size()]; //This is a problematic line

strcpy (cstr, location.c_str());

void write(const char* c)
{
    const char* fileLocation = cstr;
    //const char* fileLocation = g_pathName;
    FILE *f = fopen(fileLocation,"a+"); // This is the problematic line right here. 
    if(f!=NULL)
    {
        fputs(c,f); // append to end of file 
        fclose(f);  // save so no entries are lost without being flushed
        }
}


int main ()
{  
  write("test");

  cout << "done";

  _getch();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon at `...{ cout << "user not found" }...`

Comment: Also, don't wrap the path in quotes, it's not needed.

Comment: You don't need quotes around the file name.  It isn't being processed by the shell command interpreter, or anything like that.

Comment: what is the value of f - is it NULL or non-null?  Thinking that it is NULL because of the quotes (as noted above)

Comment: The value of f would be a pointer to the open file?

Comment: I also cannot use the sprintf call to format the string without parenthesis. I have tried `sprintf(pathName, "\C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\text.txt\", userName);`$, however it yields a compiler error. Any ideas to format that string w/out quotes?

Comment: Yes f is a pointer to the open file.  If fopen failed, the value will be NULL.  Just curious.

Comment: sprintf(pathName, "C:\\Users\\\"%s\"\\Desktop\\text.txt", userName); - have quotes around the username only, not the whole string. This will fix your code

Comment: Please accept an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. It contributes to the overall quality of the site. :)

Comment: @user6606: Still testing, these are several solutions to work through.

Comment: @YePhlcK: That doesn't work, Windows can't read a path with quotes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from `shlobj.h`:

```
const char *szFileName = "text.txt";
const char *szContent = "test string";

char szPath[_MAX_PATH];

SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, szPath, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);

strcat(szPath, "\\");
strcat(szPath, szFileName);

FILE *pFile = fopen(szPath, "a+");

if(pFile != NULL)
{
    fputs(szContent, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: Can't get this to work but would like to as it should work with the rest of my code. After `include <shlobj.h>`$ the compiler (dev c++) continues to give me an error.  `SHGetSpecialFolderPath' undeclared (first use this function)`$. Any ideas what that could be, possibly another import?

Comment: Maybe it's some `#ifdef` code failing from the include, try using `#define _WIN32_IE 0x0400`. If this doesn't work, I recommend using VC++ Express.

Comment: Another possible solution I found, is to include `shellapi.h` before `shlobj.h`, and go to *Dev-C++ Project Settings* and add the `libshell32.a` library.

Comment: I'm hoping this code will work. I cannot find this `libshell32.a`$ library for C++. I have however found `shell32.a`$ but I would imagine this is a different. Would you know where I could download this? Thank you for your continued assistance.

Comment: Maybe it's the same library, try linking it... But again, I recommend you to use either VC++ Express or BCC32 (*free command line tools*), they have total support for API calls.

Comment: I'll try installing it as a last resort, it's a very big install and I'm sure problems will arise using a different compiler with the other code in the program. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I've managed to download Dev-C++, and created a new project with all the default settings (C++ Project, Win32 Console), and made this code: http://pastebin.com/sby3JRMk It compiled and executed fine. I didn't even need to edit the project settings nor link any library...

Comment: Thank you for your continued support. Still can't get it, getting the same error on Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 & Win 7 SP1. I'm looking for a small Microsoft compiler that doesn't have many dependencies to try it there as this may possibly be a bug somewhere.

Comment: I also found this question interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863674/how-to-use-shell32-dll-from-c-console-application

Comment: I've noticed others using this API call add a `#include "stdafx.h"` which to my understanding is a MS only deal.

Comment: All that you talked about is related to VC++. `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` is supported by the compiler in VC++, and `stdafx.h` is a file created by VC++ when you create a project with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing semicolon at line 9 where it says:

```
...{ cout << "user not found" }...
```

Semicolons are not optional in C++, you need them for a working program. Also, as stated in the comments, you do not need quotes around the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) with FOLDERID_Desktop to get the path to the desktop, then add a file name to the end. You also almost certainly want to do the manipulation on `std::string`s, then when you've created the full name, use the `.c_str` member function to retrieve the name as a C-style string. Unless you have a *really* specific reason to do otherwise, you're probably better off using a `std::ofstream` instead of a C-style `FILE *` as well (and in that case if your compiler is current, you can probably pass the `std::string` object directly as the name).

Edit: some quick demo code creating and writing to a file on the user's desktop:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

std::string GetKnownFolderPath(REFKNOWNFOLDERID f) {
    PWSTR sys_path;

    SHGetKnownFolderPath(f, 0, NULL, &sys_path);

    DWORD size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, sys_path, -1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);

    std::string path(size, ' ');

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, sys_path, -1, &path[0], size, NULL, NULL);

    // We're finished with the string the system allocated:
    CoTaskMemFree(sys_path);

    // WideCharToMultiByte leaves space for a NUL terminator we don't need
    path.resize(path.size()-1);   
    return path;
}

int main() {
    std::string path(GetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop));

    path += "\\test.txt";

    std::ofstream test(path.c_str());

    test << "This is a test";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I'm googling that API call right now. I have to use the FILE pointer though as a lot of my code is reliant on it. Can you specify what you mean by a manipulation of std::string? IE declaring a string and using concatenation?

Comment: @Jorge: yes -- instead of `sprintf`, for example.

Comment: Jerry, I tried following this advice but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if that the file location must be a `const char`. I'm not worried about using the API call at this point, right now I just want to figure out how to pass a file location into another variable. Easier to explain in code.

Comment: I have appended the code above where I followed your advice and used c_str. Still doesn't work, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Jerry, I think you might have been confused. The file location needs to be passed into fopen as a const char not string.

Comment: He meant a C++ string has the method `.c_str()`, which converts it to C stirng (char *). So instead of passing for example `mystring` to the function, pass `mystring.c_str()`.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. I still get `10 C:\Dev-Cpp\test.cpp REFKNOWNFOLDERID' was not declared in this scope ` and `30 C:\Dev-Cpp\test.cpp FOLDERID_Desktop' undeclared (first use this function)` errors. It must be an issue with the compiler as 2 people are now reporting success with the same code. I'm going to try a MS compiler and report back with results.

Comment: I finally got it to work in Dev C++. My problem was that I put `#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500` after my include section instead of before. Many thanks to everyone in this thread who have helped